# Android disable tabview sliding from horizontal ScrollView inside a tabview

Tags: android, nativescript, angular2-nativescript

I have this annoying issue with my native-script app(like google play store app) in android that every-time I scroll horizontally in a ScrollView inside a TabView, frequently the adjacent TabView gets slid in when I reach the end of that ScrollView. Is there any way to disable or get rid of that sliding issue of tabs?

Answer (score 0):

You can disable swipe between tabs (which reacts when you reach end of scrollview) by overriding the underlying view pager. Hopefully it becomes easier in the next version of {N}.